# Different behavior depending upon how screen is turned off

Tags: android, screen, behavior

I am finding a weird situation depending upon how the screen is turned off.  If Android turns off the screen or the power button is pressed to turn off the screen, my app as expected is `paused`.  When the power button is pressed to turn the screen back on, the app `resumes` **no issues**.  This is true for a few moments or when tens of minutes pass.

Here's where it deviates.  If `my app turns the screen off`, my app `pauses` as expected, but my app is also **killed** immediately.

When the screen is turned back on with the power button, the app is no longer running

I have set up logging that confirms this, but why the difference in behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you are seeing is actually expected, there's a priority for each of the processes running in an Android Device, once your application goes to pause it might become elegible by the OS to get rid of it if another process with higher priority requires memory, as per google's documentation:

> The Android system tries to maintain an application process for as
>   long as possible, but eventually needs to remove old processes to
>   reclaim memory for new or more important processes. To determine which
>   processes to keep and which to kill, the system places each process
>   into an "importance hierarchy" based on the components running in the
>   process and the state of those components. Processes with the lowest
>   importance are eliminated first, then those with the next lowest
>   importance, and so on, as necessary to recover system resources.

As explained before "based on the components running in the process" means that your application might not be highly ranked in the OS, since you might have not Service running, etc, hence it is being killed eventually...

You can look at this document: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html, it explains the process life cycle and should give you a better understanding on what to do to deal with it...

Also in the battle to make battery last longer in Android devices there's a:
Suspend/Resume state on the device.
Suspend and resume happen in a three-step sequence and thus are best discussed 
together. Basically, when the device is suspended with the power button or the screen saver timeout expires, the device suspends. If the power button is pressed again, it 
resumes to the lock-screen. At this point, if the user unlocks the device, the application 
is resumed. If the user waits several seconds without unlocking the lock screen, the 
device will suspend again.

> Since this is explicitly a low-power state, the application should
>   have stopped all  rendering and sound, and likely any background
>   processing that isn’t 100% required to  keep the app alive.

Regards!

Comment: How does this explain the DIFFERENCE in behavior?  I can recreate this every time I test it.  If this was the cause, I would expect my app to die regardless of how the screen is turned off.  As it stands, it only is killed when the app itself turns the screen off, and immediately after it is turned off.

Comment: I believe I found the cause for the difference.  When the tablet screen is turned off from the app, the tablet goes into a state the triggers a `wake lock` when the power button is pressed to turn the screen on.  This is not the case as stated in the post, at least not in the short time that I tested the power button turning the screen off.  If it does, it has been outside the window of testing.  Giving app `wake lock permission` in `manifest` resolves the discrepancy. Getting my head around this has been an adventure.  Thanks for the guidance!